# Gulp SASS copies subfolders

Tags: sass, gulp

I've set up gulp and sass file compiler. Below is the contents of the gulpfile.js:

```
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('src/assets/scss/**/*')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/assets/css'))
});
```

My folder structure is:

```
src/
  assets/
    scss/
      theme.scss <!-- main file -->
      components/
        _.scss <!-- extra files -->
```

What I want is to basically compile theme.scss into theme.css. However, I also get the `/components` folder copied inside the `src/assets/css` folder (though empty). Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `gulp.src('src/assets/scss/**/*')` might be the issue.

Try changing this to `gulp.src('src/assets/scss/**/*.scss')`